# Batch file to recursively delete subdirectories with a specific name

Tags: command-line, batch-file, batch-processing

This should be relatively simple, here is my situation; I have copied the trunk contents from my local copy of subversion repositories, I use the SVN client Tortoise which creates hidden folders named ".svn" inside each subdirectory. For general use, and to prevent problems when moving from one subversion server to another (otherwise I would just merge), I would like some help putting together a batch file that will recursively go through the directory specified and delete any folders named ".svn" - I could write some C# but I am very busy at the minute and I can imagine this pretty much being a one liner for you CMD guru's. A chance to get easy answer and voteup. Please dont hate for being lazy I need a quick solution Thanks! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not neccessary.

You should use the Tortoise client to export your working copy to another directory.
You can drag and drop (with a right click) and then select export.
This copy all versioned files, but creates no .svn directories.

You could also drop the directory at itself.